# Passing SVG paths with template syntax in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

I´m working on a project where i combine angular8 and d3 and
ran in some troubles when i tried to pass my svg paths to the html component
by template binding.

And since i think this should be possible i don't get the complain about the missing moveto command...

Help appreciated, thanks :)

html:

```
div class="container-fluid">
      <svg [style]="style">
        <g class="arcs">
            <path *ngFor="let arc of arcs" d="arc.path" fill="arc.fill"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
this.arcs = this.data.sort(
      (a, b) =>  Math.abs(a.polarity) - Math.abs(b.polarity)
    ).map(d => {
      return {
        path: areaGen([
          [this.xScale(d3.timeMonth.offset(d.createdAt, -2)), this.yScale(0)],
          [this.xScale(d.createdAt), this.yScale(d.polarity)],
          [this.xScale(d3.timeMonth.offset(d.createdAt, 2)), this.yScale(0)]
        ]),
        fill: this.colors(d.favoriteCount),
        data: d
      }
    })
```

arcs[0]:

```
path: "M42.45491108257615,350C42.45491108257615,350,181.6795182101832,349.99999999999994,251.27399836212564,350C320.84472207707205,349.99999999999994,459.9505470155457,350,459.9505470155457,350L459.9505470155457,350C459.9505470155457,350,320.84472207707205,349.9999999999999,251.27399836212564,350C181.6795182101832,350,42.45491108257615,350,42.45491108257615,350Z"
fill: "#fde725"
data:
  source: "Twitter for iPhone"
  text: "Thank you @GLFOP!"
  createdAt: Wed Oct 30 2019 20:21:54 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) {}
  retweetCount: 11113
  favoriteCount: 38294
  polarity: 0
__proto__: Object
```

Console.Error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "arc.path".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser throws this error since you're passing `arc.path` string to the `svg.d` attribute but it should be path with coordinates.

You should be using correct attribute binding for your `d` and `fill` attributes:

```
d="arc.path" fill="arc.fill"

             ||
             \/

[attr.d]="arc.path" [attr.fill]="arc.fill"
```